# How can I make a div which "bleeds" an image as you scroll the page

Tags: jquery, html

So many times I have been browsing and I see an effect in which a div shows an image, and as you scroll down the page, the image shifts down (inside the div).

For example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compete
(Scroll halfway down the page)

I am trying to replicate the effect you see on the above link. I have attempted this:

```
<div style="height: 200%; width: 100%; background-image: url(...)">
<div style="height: 66.66%; width: 100%; background-color: white;"></div>
<div style="height: 66.66%; width: 100%;"></div>
<div style="height: 66.66%; width: 100%; background-color: white;"></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I know it isn't very much to go on, sorry, but I can use answers different from my above approach. jQuery and Bootstrap can be used.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This is very helpful!! Exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.static-background {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/cY0blMA.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 600px; 
}
.content-container {
    height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean non dignissim urna, eget vestibulum metus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis sodales ultricies sem, id tempor nulla mollis sed. Nulla facilisis finibus bibendum. Aliquam id justo neque.
</div>

<div class="static-background"></div>

<div class="content-container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean non dignissim urna, eget vestibulum metus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis sodales ultricies sem, id tempor nulla mollis sed. Nulla facilisis finibus bibendum. 
</div>

</body>
```

I think this is the effect you're trying to achieve. You just create an empty `div` element with a fixed background and height.

Comment: Looks like you may need to have a fallback for mobile support: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-att

Comment: Yes, I might, but now trying to make my site mobile friendly will be a nightmare...

Comment: excellent solution! could use a media query to avoid the problem of mobile support

Answer (score 0):

This type of effect is called parallax and is better accomplished with CSS and minimal Javascript to increase performance. Here is an example and write-up of the effect you're looking for: http://callmenick.com/post/advanced-parallax-scrolling-effect.

Basically, you use Javascript to listen for page scrolling. On scroll, you offset the background image position based on a fraction of the page scroll offset. Example (from source):

```
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
      speed = 0.5;

  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is called **Parallax**.

**Parallax** is when the background content or image in your case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.

There are many references you can take a look. Among all [this](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) is one of the best article I have came across that demonstrate this topic.

Comment: A comment would always be helpful on how to improve an answer!